# 400 Bad request from some websites when replaying the captured HTTP/2 request packets using TLS wrapper

Tags: python, ssl, web, scapy, http2

I am sending HTTP/2 request to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) using Curl utility and the server is responding lawfully. After this, I capture the request packets using tcpdump (packets are decrypted using PolarProxy). Then my python script (tls wrapper) reads the payload of these request packets using scapy and subsequently, sends it to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) using tls wrapper (see code below). However, Google is returning back 400 Bad request error though I am replaying the exact same request that is sent using curl. This approach is working for some websites (twitter, tmall, etc.) however it is not working for websites like google, youtube, etc. Following is the screenshot of the HTTP/2 request packets captured in `curl_wwwgoogle.pcap` file.

[image: HTTP/2 request packets]

My python script is:

```
import socket
import ssl
import requests
from scapy.all import *
from hpack import Encoder, Decoder

p=rdpcap('curl_wwwgoogle.pcap')

HOST, PORT = 'www.google.com', 443

payload=p[3][Raw].load+p[4][Raw].load+p[5][Raw].load+p[6][Raw].load

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(10)

wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)

try:
    wrappedSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
    wrappedSocket.send(payload)
    response = wrappedSocket.recv(1280)
    http_response = repr(response)
    http_response_len = len(http_response)
except:
    print("Connection error")
print(http_response)

wrappedSocket.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are announcing HTTP/2 using ALPN, i.e. something like this:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.set_alpn_protocols(["h2"])
wrappedSocket = ctx.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=HOST)
```

Comment: Thnx much Steffen :-). This resolved the issue. Now I am getting the proper HTTP/2 responses.

Answer (score 1):

Are you decrypting both the curl request and the python request with PolarProxy? If so, have you verified that the HTTP/2 contents of these two requests 100% identical?

Comment: Yes Erik, I verified that the request content sent using curl is exactly similar to the request content sent using my python script. I was also anticipating both these requests to be exactly the same as I am not altering the packet contents anywhere in my python script.

Comment: I accidentally entered my question as an answer instead of a comment [facepalm]. Sorry about that. Nevertheless, great to see that @steffen-ullrich figured out that the issue was the missing "h2" ALPN, that makes a lot of sense.